# QuickMapServices only providing OSM and NASA

Tags: qgis, quickmapservices

I am trying to use maps from QuickMapServices, but only options for OSM and NASA are available.

QGIS version: 3.26.2

I set the CRS to WGS 84 (EPSG:4326).

I've tried restarting QGIS and my computer. I've uninstalled and reinstalled the plugin.

In the settings, I checked visibility, and there are no options to select other maps.

[image: screenshot of qgis with only two options for QMS]

Comment: Did you look at the more services tab?

Comment: Yes, that was the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in a comment, I needed to select the "More Services" tab and select "Get contributed pack"
[image]